# Worksheet copy to include copy of Sheet Buttons

Tags: excel, copy, worksheet-function, vba

I have a workbook where I have a worksheet that is copied by the user hitting a button (runs the code below). I want to make a copy of the worksheet as a new instance (this part is working) and also include the buttons on the copied sheet (this is where I am having trouble in later versions of excel).

The code works in older versions of excel but in 2010 and above the worksheet is copied but the buttons are not.

My current code is as follows;

```
Private Sub NewOrderSheet()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim pN As String
Dim pNB As String
Dim pNC As String
Dim pND As String
pN = Worksheets("ProjectDetails").Range("B5").Text
pND = ("Order Number: " & pN)
pNB = InputBox(pND)
If Len(pNB) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "An order number must be given to be able to generate a new order.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
Else
End If
pNC = pN & "-" & pNB
Worksheets("QuoteSheet").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).name = pNC
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Basically I create a new instance of the worksheet and then allow the user to give the worksheet a new name (in this case a new order).

The worksheet contains 2 buttons;
Button 1 - Copies the worksheet into a new workbook and removes all formulas
Button 2 - Formats the used range for printing

I have searched the questions and tried a number of variations but cannot seem to get the buttons to copy over.

I am very new to VB for excel so my apologies in advance if this is something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I checked all security concerning settings and tried everything. And then I found out that deleting the %Temp% Folder helps.
The true reason is, you have to search for a "MSForms.exd" File and delete it.
Then everything works fine again (: